# Multiple data frame to single excel file(two different sheets) in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes processed from the database. I need to export those data frames into excel(libreoffice calc) in two different sheets.

```
DF1:
    symbol    datetime    value
0    MOV    06:25:02    148767
1    TBI    06:25:02    267198
2    HY     06:25:02    56232
3    KAMN   06:25:02    2247    

DF2:
    symbol    datetime    value
0    MC     06:25:02    1098560
1    AIG    06:25:02    5952267
2    CHS    06:25:02    1879192
3    VRX    06:25:02    5502438
```

I have tried the following,

```
    print df1
    wr1 = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/suresh/Desktop/20151123/symbol.ods')
    df1.to_excel(wr1, 'Sheet1')
    print df2 
    df2.to_excel(wr1, 'Sheet2')
```

Now, not able to open the excel file.

Comment: please show your efforts, SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 11):

If passing an existing `ExcelWriter` object, then the sheet will be added to the existing workbook. This can be used to save different `DataFrames` to one workbook:

[Source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) - in the end of webpage.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
DF1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
DF2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Do not forget to add, `writer.close()`, even if there is a warning message like: 

*UserWarning: Calling close() on already closed file. warn("Calling close() on already closed file.")*

This will prevent errors, when trying to open the file