# Creating multiple spreadsheets in one excel file with Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

As title, I need to create multiple spreadsheets into a excel file with Pandas. While [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874648/multiple-data-frame-to-single-excel-filetwo-different-sheets-in-python-pandas) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981820/creating-multiple-excel-worksheets-using-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
all provided solutions, I figured my situation is a bit different. Both of the cases use something similar to:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
DF1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
DF2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

However, the problem is that I cannot afford to keep multiple dataframes in my memory at the same time since each of them are just too big. My data can be the complicated version of this:
`df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('aabb'), B=range(4), C=range(6,10)))`
`Out:   A  B  C
     0  a  0  6
     1  a  1  7
     2  b  2  8
     3  b  3  9`

I intend to use the items `['a', 'b', 'c']` in `grplist` to perform some sort of calculation and eventually generate separate spreadsheets when `data['A'] == a` through `c` :

```
data = pd.read_csv(fileloc)
grplist = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
for groups, numbers in zip(grplist, range(1, 5)):
    for category in groups:
        clean = data[(data['A'] == category) & (data['B'] == numbers)]['C']
        # --------My calculation to generate a dataframe--------
        my_result_df = pd.DataFrame(my_result)
        writer = ExcelWriter('my_path_of_excel')
        my_resultdf.to_excel(writer, 'Group%s_%s' % (numbers, category[:4]))
        writer.save()
        gc.collect()
```

Sadly my code does not create multiple spreadsheets as `groups, numbers` are looped through. I can only get the last result in the single spreadsheet lying in my excel. What can I do?

This is my very first post here. I hope I'm following every rules so this thread can end well. If anything need to be modified or improved, please kindly let me know. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('aabb'), B=range(4)))
```

loop through groups and print

```
for name, group in df.groupby('A'):
    print('{}\n\n{}\n\n'.format(name, group))

a

   A  B
0  a  0
1  a  1


b

   A  B
2  b  2
3  b  3
```

---

***`to_excel`***

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
for name, group in df.groupby('A'):
    group.to_excel(writer, name)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks [tag:piRSquared] for your prompt response. However, this does not solve my problem. I've added a few more lines to describe my data and code. I guess the ultimate question I'm asking is: "How to create a multiple spreadsheets once a time" instead of grouping them together using `.groupby()`. If I am not understanding you correctly, please let me know.